# mysql avg(min()) can it be done?

Tags: mysql

Obviously avg(min()) give me an error, so I tried this code, but it gives me wrong figures. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
select
    out_year as "Year",
    avg(dwell_time) as "Average",
    avg(av.dw_min) as "Minimum",
    avg(av.dw_max) as "Maximum"
from
    (select min(dwell_time) as dw_min, max(dwell_time) as dw_max
    from eq_dwell) av,
    eq_dwell ed
where
    inv_status = "Offdock"
group by out_year
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what it gives you vs. what you're expecting?

Comment: Your inner select will return exactly one row.  How can you then take an average?  I think you need to add `year` to the inner select and then group the inner select by year.

Comment: Never mind, I did my calculations, and realized avg(1,2,3,4) is not the same as avg( avg(1,2) + avg(3,4) ) so is no use to do it this way. Thanks anyway for your comments.